# Object shrinks when rotated javascript

Tags: javascript, vector, rotation, game-engine, quaternions

I have been developing a basic game engine just to learn the process and I have hit a issue with my rotation function.

It works fine except that the object shrinks and appears to invert.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devcon/zt69hwg4/) that illustrates my point.

I think the problem would be in the rotation code its self but i'm not positive.

```
function Rotation(vec, rot){
if(Math.acos((vec.x + vec.y + vec.z -1)/2) === 0) { return vec; }

var qVec = new Quaternion(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z, 0);
qVec = Quaternions.multiply(qVec, rot);
qVec = Quaternions.multiply(qVec, rot.conjugate());
return new Vector3(qVec.x, qVec.y, qVec.z);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

First, the rotation quaternion is not normalized, so it's inverse is not the same as its conjugate. Rotation by a quaternion is defined by:

[image: formula]

Where `q` is the vector you're rotating around, `p` is the vector you're rotating, and `p'` is the final rotated vector.

So this is defined using the *inverse* of q, which is defined as `conjugate(q) / magnitude(q)^2`. In the case where q is normalized, `magnitude(q)^2 == 1`, so it's the same as just multiplying by the conjugate.

Also note the order of operations here. Quat multiplications are **non-commutative** so their order matters.

You can fix this by normalizing your rotation quaternion, and fixing the order of operations:

```
var qVec = new Quaternion(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z, 0);
qVec = Quaternions.multiply(rot.normalize(), qVec);
qVec = Quaternions.multiply(qVec, rot.conjugate());
return new Vector3(qVec.x, qVec.y, qVec.z);
```

Second, you want to define your rotation quat as normal to the plane you want to rotate around. In this case, you want to rotate around the x-y plane. The z-axis is normal to this plane, so we want to define the rotation vector along the z-axis:

```
function update(){
    for(var i = 0; i < gameObjects.length; i++){
        gameObjects[i].rotation = euler(new Vector3(0, 0, frames/100));
    }
}
```

With these changes, I was able to get the box rotating correctly.

(In terms of why it was scaling up/down, I'm not 100% sure. Still trying to figure that out.)

Comment: Awesome! This helps allot. I think that the current shrinking might be because I'm not projecting the square onto a camera's plane yet, basically ignoring the z-axis when I draw.